# Can someone help me write a matlab program to count from 0 to N^M in base N?

Tags: matlab

I've been trying to teach myself Matlab in my spare time using the "Cody" challenge problems, but I have been stuck on this one for two weeks.

Instructions:

Return an array of numbers which (effectively) count from 0 to N^M-1 in base N. The result should be returned in a matrix, with each column representing a number. Each element represents a digit of the number. Lower-indexed rows represent lower-significance digits.

Example 1 (Binary): countInBaseN(2,2) (counts from 0 to 3 in base 2)

ans =

```
 0     0     1     1
 0     1     0     1
```

Example 2 (Ternary): countInBaseN(2,3) (counts from 0 to 8 in base 3)

ans =

```
 0     0     0     1     1     1     2     2     2
 0     1     2     0     1     2     0     1     2
```

This is the code that I tried, but I just can't get it to work. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
function y = countInBaseN(M,N)
for i=0:N.^M
x = dec2base(i, N)
x=num2str(x+1) - '0'
ans=[ans x’]
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code in question, but we also need to know what exactly "not working" means.

Answer (score 2):

```
double(dec2base(1:N^M,N)-'0')
```

Your error was to use `num2str`, which views the whole output as a decimal number. Instead it requires operations based on the single character, which is basically `double`

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't how you want to do it... but it can be done in a single line, no loops, no strings:

```
floor(mod(bsxfun(@rdivide, 0:N^M-1, N.^(M-1:-1:0).'),N))
```

Comment: @user3020151 I suggest you observe the partal results: `bsxfun(...)`, then `mod(...)` etc. And if there's something you don't see clear, feel free to ask me